# HTML Helper in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Can someone pls tell me what i'm doing wrong?
I want to make a checkbox using the HTML helper.

```
 <ul>
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("chk1", true, "checkbox1")</li>
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("chk2", true, "checkbox2")</li>
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("chk3", true, "checkbox3")</li>
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("chk4", true, "checkbox4")</li>
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("chk5", true, "checkbox5")</li>
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("chk6", true, "checkbox6")</li>
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("chk7", true, "checkbox7")</li>
</ul>
```

When i run the view, i see the checkbox all checked which is what i want. 
However it doesnt display the labels Checkbox1, checkbox2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows,

`<%= Html.CheckBox("checkbox7") %>`
`<label for="checkbox7" style="display:inline">checkbox7</label>`